# MySQL Community Server - What is it exactly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, database-management

Hello fellow StackOverFlow-ians. I am currently learning about **PHP** and I have found out that it is deeply related to "**MySQL**". I looked it up, and what I think is that "**SQL**" is a language used to help "**Database Management Systems**" run "**Relational Databases**".

I have installed "**MySQL Community Server**" on the [Website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). I have a **command prompt** and a few files now installed on my computer. *Is this one database, or is this a tool for managing databases, and I have to install a database?*

What I would like to know is, what this community server is exactly, and what I need to get started (links and tutorials would be appreciated). If what I said at the start was wrong, then please tell me - **I cannot find valid information anywhere**.

*Thanks in advance - **0wendaman***

Comment: it's the "free" version of mysql, without any of the enterprise add-on features for which you have to pay. think of it as "mysql lite".

Comment: Any basic mysql tutorial will do you for now.

Comment: It is a RDBMS (relational database management system). It is a tool for managing databases, but you do not need to install anything further to use databases (you might want to install something that will help you to programmatically interact with the server, however).

Comment: Thank you guys! I understand it now. You all had very helpful information :)

Comment: Since you don't know what sql is, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Also, my opinion is that the database design is the most important part of most applications.  I've also heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL offical docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html) are good resource to learn

You can learn at [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/) as well

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is also useful for beginners

[Reading this book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Mysql_The_Complete_Reference.html?id=RxqMdsOzaVIC) may help you alot

Comment: Thank you! I might have been a bit stupid, not looking into the actual website, but there weren't much helpful links I could find.

Comment: w3fools isn't useful for anyone who intends to write useful/secure code. the site is garbage. just because it comes up up high in google search results means nothing.

Comment: I actually found useful references in SQL - that I intend to use. Thanks for your opinion though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (Wamp) its good for using db.

Comment: Thank you for the resource - but I would have needed to understand how databases work first, which is in the best answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: np, only showing for future use when you learn php and mysql that wamp can be useful to create your website